# Silverlight/.Net RIA Services - Authorization Working Sample?

Tags: asp.net, authorization, wcf-ria-services, asp.net-authorization

I have followed numerous tutorials and walkthroughs/blogs about the capabilities that Ria Services brings to the table when using Silverlight with ASP.Net. Essentially I am looking for a live working example of the authorization functionality that Ria Services can apparently take hold of from ASP.Net. (Even better if it works with ASP.NET MVC too)

[Example of failed to work Ria Services authorization implementation](http://alpascual.com/blog/part-3-accessing-security-and-authentication-in-silverlight-using-net-ria-services/)

[Navigate to the live demo link on this page....fails](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-applications-with-.NET-RIA-Service-Part-1-Introduction.aspx)

[This one may work however I couldn't get it to work on my office computer(strange setup that seems to break code for no reason)](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-3-with-Ria-Authentication-service.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check here: [enter link description here](http://qualityofdata.com/category/saf-simple-authorization-framework/). There is a bunch of posts giving samples. It not exactly what you want but has a walk-through for setting up full authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Brad Abrams has some good information. Also note that the new "Silverlight Business Application" template in the Visual Studio -> New Project dialog has authentication set up already where you can mess around with it without having to figure out how to set it up first.

http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/10/05/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-26-authentication-and-personalization.aspx

[C# Silverlight with RIA Services Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478106/c-silverlight-with-ria-services-authentication/1604908#1604908)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you haven't configured your environment yet. In the `machine.config` file for the framework version in use, you will find LocalSqlServer defined. You should edit this definition to point at the SQL Server serving up the aspnetdb database that you want to use (and if you don't have one then start by setting up that).

Machine.config is generally in `c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.something\config`

For development you have to configure this in the workstation machine.config to make the debugger's webserver use your production authentication database. For production you have to do the same configuration on the production webserver.

There are different paths for 64 and 32 bit framework instances, and if like me you have 32 and 64 bit editions of version 2, 3, 3.5 and 4 then you have *eight* "root" configuration files. If you hunt them all down and set *all* of them it will save untold confusion later.

Answer (score 0):

This is from my blog last october:

The Business Application Template for Silverlight comes with a login and register pages.  It is very easy to connect these to a ASPNETDB.mdf.

Just add a LocalSqlServer connection string to your web.config file.  For example, here is what I use to connect to Sql Server.

It’s almost too easy!

If you are using SqlExpress on your dev machine, it gets even easier.  You don’t have to do anything.  Just create a new Silverlight Business App and fire it up.  Go to the log-on page and register.  It will be slow, but in the background, your ASPNETDB was just created and attached, and you will be logged in.  If you then look in the Web.config file, you won’t see a connection string anywhere, as the defaults are used for this piece of magic.  Of course, a real world connection is going to need it’s own connection string like the above.

Greg