# C# Silverlight with RIA Services Authentication

Tags: c#, silverlight, authentication, wcf-ria-services

Does anyone have any good samples, resources, pointers etc. for C# Silverlight with RIA Services basic authentication or Roles?!

All of the tutorials I've checked out aren't too great....

help appreciated greatly.

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brad Abrams has some good information.  Also note that the new "Silverlight Business Application" template in the Visual Studio -> New Project dialog has authentication set up already where you can mess around with it without having to figure out how to set it up first.

http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/10/05/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-26-authentication-and-personalization.aspx